# Major slowdown and sluggishness observed when switching from 10.13 to 10.15

Tags: performance

I have a late 2012 Mac mini (2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 w/8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3).

I meant to update to the latest 10.14 in order to fix a persistent Mail problem, but missed the switch-over deadline and had to install 10.15.1 instead, as a result of which I noticed a major slowdown of most observable processes and applications (at least the Mail problem did get solved).

Why might this be?

I don't want to go down the conspiracy theory path (Apple intentionally slowing down older Macs in order to make us buy newer ones) - I would like to hear a sensible technical answer/explanation from someone in the know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the Mini is still using rotating rust, (this model came standard with 500 GB or 1 TB 5400-rpm _hard drive_,) this could be the source of the perceived and/or actual slowdown. This Mini was also available with a 256GB SSD or 1TB Fusion drive. If I were you, I'd upgrade the Mini with a large SSD.

Comment: If you want to try 10.14, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190